# Why isn't my Auth Guard Working? Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, authorization

I have created a simple AuthGuard that verifies a token, and returns a true/false response. The API Server (Express) and the Auth Service works fine, but there is some bug going on at `if (this.isValid())` because no matter what, the user is always redirected to login.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private _authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate() {
    if (this.isValid()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      // not logged in so redirect to login page
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }

  }
  isValid(): boolean {
    let isValid = false;
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
      this._authService.verifyToken().subscribe(validToken => {
        isValid = validToken === true;
      });
    }
    console.log(isValid);
    return isValid;
  }
}
```

Where in my `isValid` function is causing this problem?

Comment: You never get an error logged in the console? Have you debugged the `IsValid` function? Is your auth service working? What does the `console.log(isValid);` reveal?

Comment: Console log reveals isValid is true. I got no errors, and my auth service is working

Answer (score 1):

You will always end up receiving `false` from `isValid` because `this._authService.verifyToken()` is an async operation. Async operations subscribe callback will be executed when the data arrives from your api point. Hence it will execute

```
console.log(isValid);
return isValid;
```

before the subscribe callback.

You can move the logic inside the subscribe:

```
isValid(): any{
    let isValid = false;
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
      this._authService.verifyToken().subscribe(validToken => {
        isValid = validToken === true;
        console.log(isValid);
        return isValid;
      });
    }    
}
```

More info on: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: I get the following error: `TS2355: A function who's declared type is not 'void' or 'any' must return a type.`

Comment: @Moshe I've updated my answer. `isValid()`s return type should be `any` at this point